# Как добавить сортировку по имени файла?

Tags: c++, winapi

Программа выводит список файлов и папок из заданной директории. Как реализовать сортировку по алфавиту? При выводе списка.

```
int main()
{

    WIN32_FIND_DATAW wfd;

    HANDLE const hFind = FindFirstFileW(L"D:\\Учебка\\*", &wfd);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFind)
    {
        do
        {
            std::wcout  << &wfd.cFileName[0]  << std::endl;
        } while (NULL != FindNextFileW(hFind, &wfd));

        FindClose(hFind);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Получить все, отсортировать, потом выводить. Вроде очевидное решение-то...

Answer (score 1):

Системные вызовы [FindFirstFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) / [FindNextFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) предоставляют список элементов, подходящие под критерии поиска, в неопределенном порядке (который может быть различным к тому же для разных файловых систем).

Поэтому единственный вариант - получить весь список файлов (например, считать в память) после чего произвести его сортировку по требуемым критериям.